# Need help for algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I need to create an algorithm, which does the follwing:

I have an 8-digit number;

- digits 3, 4, 5, 6 are given (known).
- digits 1, 2, 7, 8 are unknown.
- digit 7 is the sum of digits 1, 2, 3
- digit 8 is the sum of digits 4, 5, 6

I want to put in two random numbers for 1. and 2. digit and let the algorithm do the rest.

Short:

```
given: d3, d4, d5, d6
input: d1, d2

algorithm:

d7 := d1 + d2 + d3
d8 := d4 + d5 + d6
```

I found this way so far but I have a problem with the method. Can anyone help?

```
public class Number {
  private int d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8;

  public Number(int d3, int d4, int d5, int d6) {
    this.d3 = d3;
    this.d4 = d4;
    this.d5 = d5;
    this.d6 = d6;
  }

  public void algorithm(int d1, int d2) {
    this.d1 = d1;
    this.d2 = d2;

    this.d7 = this.d1 + this.d2 + this.d3;
    this.d8 = this.d4 + this.d5 + this.d6;
  }
}
```

Comment: what about the 7th digit?

Comment: "Let the algorithm do the rest" ... of what?  You haven't specified the output of this algorithm.

Comment: What "problem" do you have with the method? It appears to do the calculation you described.

Comment: the algorithm should add digit 1 and 2 and calculate the last two digit as described.

Comment: i cant run this code. it keeps asking for a method with public static void main ...

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is correct except it does not handle invalid inputs (ie. where input digits or the calculated digits are incorrect). Other than that, to run the code, please add public static void main method as every java program start its execution from this method. Attaching sample working code for your reference.

```
public class Number {
private Integer d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8;

private boolean isDigit(int digit) {
    return digit >= 0 && digit < 10;
}

private boolean isNotDigit(int digit) {
    return !isDigit(digit);
}

public Number(int d3, int d4, int d5, int d6) throws IllegalDigitException {

    if (isNotDigit(d3) || isNotDigit(d4) || isNotDigit(d5) || isNotDigit(d6))
        throw new IllegalDigitException("All entered digits must be positive and less than 10");

    this.d3 = d3;
    this.d4 = d4;
    this.d5 = d5;
    this.d6 = d6;
}

public void algorithm(int d1, int d2) throws IllegalDigitException {
    if (isNotDigit(d1) || isNotDigit(d2))
        throw new IllegalDigitException("All entered digits must be positive and less than 10");
    this.d1 = d1;
    this.d2 = d2;

    this.d7 = this.d1 + this.d2 + this.d3;
    this.d8 = this.d4 + this.d5 + this.d6;

    if (isNotDigit(d7) || isNotDigit(d8))
        throw new IllegalDigitException("All calculated digits must be positive and less than 10, please try with other d1 and d2 values");
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return new Integer(d1.toString() + d2.toString() + d3.toString() + d4.toString() + d5.toString() + d6.toString() + d7.toString() + d8.toString()).toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Number n = null;
    try {
        n = new Number(10, 2, 3, 4);
        n.algorithm(0, 1);
        System.out.println("Number is " + n.toString());
    } catch (IllegalDigitException e) {
        System.out.println("Error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}


class IllegalDigitException extends Exception {
    public IllegalDigitException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

}